# Android SQLite User Login doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication

I actually implemented an SQLite database into my app and made a Login activity. So when the app starts I start my Login activity and in there I Access the database. So the user puts in Name and Password and presses "anmelden" then the database checks if the user already exists, and if so, if the Password is correct, if it's correct the activity finishes and the user can continue. If the Password is incorrect but the user exists, nothing happens and a toast will be displayed. And if there is no user with the Name given, then a new user will be created with that Password and Name.

My Problem is now that when I create a new user everything seems to work fine, but if I restart the app and try to Login with the same data, it still creates a new user.

I sadly can't tell how this Looks in the database cuz I don't have a rooted phone atm, so I hope you guys can help me since I don't find the mistake

This is my "Anmeldung"(Login) class

```
public class Anmeldung extends Activity {
public Datasource datasource = new Datasource(this);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_anmeldung);
}

//// OnClick-Methoden

/// public void anmelden(View view) {//the Login method

    EditText t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
    String name = t.getText().toString();
    EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_passwort);
    String psswd = e.getText().toString();
    datasource.open();
    if (datasource.UserExists(name)) {
        if (datasource.correctPassword(name, psswd)) {
            datasource.close();

            finish();
        } else {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Falsches Passwort", 3);
            toast.show();
        }
    } else {
        datasource.createUser(name, psswd, 0, 0);
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Neuen Nutzer erstellt", 3);
        toast.show();

        finish();
    }


}
```

}

This is my datasource class with all the relevant methods

```
public class Datasource {
//Log-Tag
private static final String LOG_TAG = Datasource.class.getSimpleName();
//Datenbankspezifische Variablen
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private Datahelper dbHelper;
private String[] columns = {Datahelper.COLUMN_ID, Datahelper.COLUMN_TYPE, Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME, Datahelper.COLUMN_EXPIRATION, Datahelper.COLUMN_OWNER};
private String[] columns_users = {Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS, Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS, Datahelper.COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS, Datahelper.COLUMN_SOAP_USERS, Datahelper.COLUMN_EP_USERS};
private String[] column_id_user = {Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS};
private String[] column_name_user = {Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS};
private String[] column_psswd_user = {Datahelper.COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS};

//Konstruktor
public Datasource(Context context) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DataSource is now creating the dbHelper");
    dbHelper = new Datahelper(context);
}

//Öffnen der Datenbank
public void open() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "asking for reference");
    database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received reference. path: " + database.getPath());

}

//Schließen der Datenbank
public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "closed database");
}








public User createUser(String name, String psswd, long soap, long ep) {
    ContentValues c = new ContentValues();
    c.put(Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS, name);
    c.put(Datahelper.COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS, psswd);
    c.put(Datahelper.COLUMN_SOAP_USERS, soap);
    c.put(Datahelper.COLUMN_EP_USERS, ep);
    long insId = database.insert(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, null, c);
    Cursor cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, columns_users, Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS + "=" + insId, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    return cursorToUser(cursor);
}

private User cursorToUser(Cursor cursor) {

    int idId = cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS);
    int idName = cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS);
    int idPsswd = cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS);
    int idSoap = cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_SOAP_USERS);
    int idEp = cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_EP_USERS);
    long id = cursor.getLong(idId);
    String name = cursor.getString(idName);
    String psswd = cursor.getString(idPsswd);
    long soap = cursor.getLong(idSoap);
    long ep = cursor.getLong(idEp);
    return new User(id, name, psswd, soap, ep);

}

public boolean UserExists(String name) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, column_id_user, Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS + " = " + name, null, null, null, null);
        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS));
        cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, column_name_user, Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
        String n = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean correctPassword(String name, String psswd) {
    try {


        Cursor cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, column_id_user, Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS + " = " + name, null, null, null, null);
        long id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS));
        cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, column_name_user, Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
        String n = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS));
        cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, column_psswd_user, Datahelper.COLUMN_ID_USERS + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
        String p = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS));
        if (n == name && psswd == p) return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

hope you can help me, tell if you Need something else:)

LOG:

```
12-20 20:33:56.684 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/Datasource: asking for reference
12-20 20:33:56.689 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/Datasource: received reference. path: /data/user/0/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner/databases/task_list.db
12-20 20:33:56.690 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: Test
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Test (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM table_users WHERE name = Test
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
12-20 20:33:56.696 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
12-20 20:33:56.697 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1328)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1175)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1046)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1214)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.ein_siedler.putzplaner.Datasource.UserExists(Datasource.java:139)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.ein_siedler.putzplaner.activities.Anmeldung.anmelden(Anmeldung.java:50)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4463)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21211)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-20 20:33:56.698 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-20 20:33:56.699 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-20 20:33:56.699 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
12-20 20:33:56.699 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-20 20:33:56.699 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-20 20:33:56.699 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-20 20:33:56.743 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/AppTracker: App Event: stop
12-20 20:33:56.795 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/AppTracker: App Event: start
12-20 20:33:56.872 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/AbstractTracker: Event success
12-20 20:33:56.878 24009-24009/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/AbstractTracker: Event success
12-20 20:33:56.955 24009-24146/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb35ec380 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9f07c660
```

DatahHelper class:

```
class Datahelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
//Strings für Datenbank
public static final String DB_NAME = "task_list.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_TASK_LIST = "task_list";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_EXPIRATION = "expiration";
public static final String COLUMN_OWNER = "owner";
public static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TASK_LIST + "(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_EXPIRATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_OWNER + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
public static final String TABLE_USERS = "table_users";
public static final String COLUMN_ID_USERS = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERS = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS = "psswd";
public static final String COLUMN_SOAP_USERS = "soap";
public static final String COLUMN_EP_USERS = "ep";
public static final String SQL_CREATE_USERS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USERS + "(" + COLUMN_ID_USERS + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME_USERS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_PSSWD_USERS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_SOAP_USERS + " INTEGER, " + COLUMN_EP_USERS + " INTEGER);";
private static final String LOG_TAG = Datahelper.class.getSimpleName();

public Datahelper(Context context) {
    //Konstruktor
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Succesfully created database: " + getDatabaseName());


}

//Erstellen einer neuen Datenbank
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "creating table " + SQL_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_USERS);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Error while creating table: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

//Änderung an Struktur
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

error log after chaning the code
but i don't exactly know how to Format this

```
    12-21 07:53:25.097 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
12-21 07:53:25.098 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
12-21 07:53:25.098 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
12-21 07:53:25.098 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:74)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.ein_siedler.putzplaner.Datasource.UserExists(Datasource.java:141)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.ein_siedler.putzplaner.activities.Anmeldung.anmelden(Anmeldung.java:47)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4463)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5233)
12-21 07:53:25.099 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21211)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5539)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
12-21 07:53:25.100 22705-22705/com.ein_siedler.putzplaner W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: In your method `UserExists` in the `catch` block add the statement `e.printStackTrace()` from there you can check the logs and you can check the logs for the error. Notify me what is the cause!

Comment: i already added the stack trace and posted the log, it's not in the Code, but someone already asked

Answer (score -1):

I think there something going wrong in your `Datasource` class and your `UserExists` function returning false; you can't see any errors because you missed `e.printStackTrace();` in every try-catch's catch exception section try to set `e.printStackTrace();` to every try-catch in `datasource` class and rebuild app and run it. Show Catlog there...

Update:

Try this function:

```
public boolean UserExists(String name) {
    try {
        Cursor cursor = database.query(Datahelper.TABLE_USERS, null, Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS + " = '" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);
        String n = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Datahelper.COLUMN_NAME_USERS));
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Check twice if you using string value in sql query it must be between ''

Comment: There is problem in your DataHelper class can you show it?

Comment: added the datahelper class

Comment: it still doesnt work but i am actually getting an IndexOutOfBounds Exception

Comment: log is addded, but i couldn't get it formatted well

Comment: I see you using unuseful code in UserExists Function fixed it